# call method in applicationwillenterforeground not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4

I'm trying to get my views to update when the user returns to the app while it is running in the background. My problem is this, I call the method that updates the view and a couple of UILabels but they dont update. The strange thing is, is that I have an NSLog in the method to ensure it is being fired. So I load the app, I hit the home button to return to the home screen, I open the app, I DO get an Log reading that the method I need fired IS indeed fired but the view sint updated. Help. Please.

Comment: You should provide some of the relevant code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use applicationDidBecomeActive for this purpose.

Template implementation has the following comment:

Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.